# How to do One on One chat in Socket.io using Node JS server?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, socket.io, chat

I am working on a Chat application. I am using [this](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat) for the chat demo app. But this is not what I want. I want to implement one on one chat in my application. But this is one-to-many chat app(Group chat). Please help me to understand the concept behind one-on-one chat using Node JS server. How to filter it?

Comment: Did you found good solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io gives you flexibility to choose who is going to recieve the message. You can explore all ways to emit an event [here](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/)

The easiest way to implement one-on-one chat is by using rooms.

You can join both users into one room and emit messages to that room.

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.join(exampleRoom);

  socket.to(exampleRoom).emit('message', "a message to everyone in the room,except me");
})
```